# What is a PTA Partner Tech Advisor, added to the Sitecore Support portal?

Tags: support

What is a `PTA Partner Tech Advisor`, added to the `Sitecore Support portal`?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore has recently launched the `Partner Technical Advisory support service`.

The Partner Technical Advisor (PTA) team is a team of expert developers and subject matter experts who provide partners with pre-sales, sales, implementation, and ongoing support and advocacy.
[image]

**Getting started:**
How to engage a PTA using Service Now, Sitecore’s case management system:

- Navigate to the [Support Portal](https://support.sitecore.com/) and log in
- Click on Support Cases
- Click on Partner Technical Advisor in the gray horizontal navigation bar
- Complete the simple form and add attachments as needed
- Click Submit (Note: You will receive an acknowledgment via email)
- All correspondence must be conducted through Service Now

**Frequently Asked Questions (FAQs):**

- Do I need to be certified to engage with a PTA?
  PTAs are intended to support partner resources who are already trained and certified (or are actively pursuing certification).
- When should I engage a PTA for implementation review?
  Requests for implementation review should be done before the commencement of the project.
- Are there any requirements for engaging a PTA in an implementation review?
  An implementation review will only be offered if the partner has put a minimum of three appropriately certified team members on the project.
- What does an engagement with a PTA look like? How often will we meet?
  A lead PTA will determine the right cadence of check-ins to be followed over the course of the project (Minimum: one check-in every two weeks).
- Can I set up a Service Level Agreement (SLA) with the PTA team?
  There are no SLAs on PTA requests. The commitment is the best effort only. Partners who need committed response times should engage with professional services.
- Can I use PTAs as an extension of my development team?
  PTAs are advisory only. They will not create deliverables for partners.
- What are some things PTAs won’t help with?
  PTAs will not assist with product defects. Suspected defects should be routed through support. PTAs also do not handle any issues related to pricing, program compliance, etc.

Do take note that only certified Sitecore Developers can raise tickets on the support portal.